# How can I order a MySQL column by a specific pattern?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with a date column. The user can put in dates like:

```
*thurs 4-21
*wed 4-28
*mon 5-5
*fri 5-17
```

But in any order. Is it possible to Order by the numbered part of the date when I get the values out of the table?

I am using PHP.

Comment: What is the datatype of the date column?

Comment: The datatype is varchar

Comment: It's a database, not a text file. It has types for a reason. Use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following concept:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY
    STR_TO_DATE
        (
            CONCAT
                (
                    '2014-', 
                    SPLIT_STR(Your_Date_Field, ' ', 2) /* This will get the part of your string that is after the space */
                ) /* This will generate a string looks like this: 2014-4-21 */
            ,'%y-%m-%d'
        ); /* Convert the whole string to date using the format '%y-%m-%d' */
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. After you get the resulted data from the table, put them into an array. then access from the back and handle the data as you want to sort. better to put the intermediate data to another temporal array.